# How to add images from Resources.resx in a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have searched a lot but cannot get what I want. I need to fill a combo box with images (114 images embedded in Resources.resx).

I am just getting list, not images. Here is my code.

```
ResourceSet rsrcSet =MyProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

            List<object> images = new List<object>();

            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rsrcSet)
            {
                //String name = entry.Key.ToString();
                //Object resource = entry.Value;
                images.Add( Don't know what will be here? );
            }

            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

            comboBox.ItemsSource = images;
```

and my XAML

```
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the easiest to use an item template. To do so we define a `DataTemplate` with `DataType` `String` and set it to the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`. In order to use `String` in XAML we need to reference the `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` assembly and namespace. For the binding we use a `ObservableCollection<string>` that holds the relative paths to your images:

**View model:**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
      this.ImageSources = new ObservableCollection<string>() { @"Resources\Icons\image.png" };      
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event fired whenever a child property changes its value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called to fire a <see cref="PropertyChanged"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"> The property name. </param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> imageSources;   
    public ObservableCollection<string> ImageSources
    {
      get => this.imageSources;
      set 
      { 
        this.imageSources = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Window.DataContext>
     <viewModels:ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItemTemplate" DataType="system:String">
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="100" Width="100"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSources}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

To make it work, your dictionary should contain the relative image paths. If not you have to convert. So instead of initializing the `ObservableCollection` in the constructor, like in the example, you can move the initialization to anywhere else.